# How Lenz's law is based on conservation of energy?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, energy-conservation, electromagnetic-induction, lenz-law

To be honest, I understood Lenz's law. It doesn't violate conservation of energy. Kinetic energy gets coverted to electromotive force (EMF). But why?

Like in case of upward thrown ball, kinetic transfers to potential. It has a reason which can be explained by Newton's law of motion, but in this case how? Why does kinetic energy change to EMF?

Comment: Energy cannot be converted into force. Also, we assume everybody here is honest and there is no need to state this.

Comment: when i said energy will be converted into force? i said why kinetic is converting to induced emf ...in ball example you can explain it using force thats all! I dont think you understood the whole context instead of my first statement-"to be honest"

Comment: I'd recommend that you describe a *particular set-up* in which an emf is generated.

Comment: ok i describe one setup; take a magnet moving towards single coiled conductor; that's all